# How to translate this conversation? 就是那种又泡又回吃的那种

Tags: translation

Hi, I just watched a street interview where girls are asked "when is a man most useful?" 男人什么时候最有用

There is a response that I don't understand: 暖被窝吧 暖被窝最有用 . 就是那种又泡又回吃的那种

Can someone help me clarify it?

Comment: It does not makes sense,

Comment: Did you hear it right? 暖被窝吧 暖被窝最有用 . 就是那种又泡又回吃的那种. It could make sense if the sentence is recast as 暖被窝吧 暖被窝最有用 . 就是那种又胖又会吃的那种. Basically, I would take it as a joke. No girl will like a piggy man who likes eating a lot of food.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

哈哈，这是一个玩笑。原文应该是“暖被窝吧 暖被窝最有用就是那种又胖又会吃的那种”。

Comment: what does 暖被窝吧 mean? "warm bedding吧". I don't really understand the grammar or meaning...

Comment: @Angus, 被窝, a set, is kind of figurative. A man in the quilt is like a bird in its nest. So, 被窝 is like a nest formed with a quilt. 暖被窝 means to warm 被窝, or as you said "warm bedding". In this context, the girl means the most useful of a man is to warm 被窝, so that she wouldn't feel cold when she go to bed. This is good especially in Winter time. Apparently, a fat man who eats a lot of food would be best fit for this function.

Comment: @Angus As dan said, but in a formal saying would be "A man who loves me, he will do sweet things for me, like warm the bed use his body when there is no heating."

Comment: @LiuYan刘研 And he's fat...

Answer (score 1):

"As a quilt, they're most useful as a quilt. So most the useful is a nice fat one who can eat a lot."

(Following Delen's re-transcription!)

Answer (score -1):

the following interpretation is suitable for 18 or above, read with cautions :)

> 暖被窩吧 暖被窩最有用 . 就是那種又泡又回吃的那種

started from 吃, it's the metaphor of "sexual intercourse", so, "回吃" is "sexual intercourse" again.

"泡", there's a word "泡妞", which means making friend with girls:

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000023468

it's pronounced similar to another character "抱" (u+62b1), which means embrace.

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=抱](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%8A%B1)

so, together, the girl expressed that:

a male (男人) is useful (有用) when, after sexual intercourse; he embrace his female partner (又泡) and eager for xxxking again (回吃).

one might workout the assumption: that it's in the context of cold environment, that two people holding each other together is warmer (暖被窩) than each one sleeps alone.